# R - get all variables created from function call

Tags: r

This is crazy, and just out of intellectual curiosity: Can I run a function in R in such a way that after the function completes I can get all variables created when the function executed?  So the ability to look into a function right before it returned?  I don't mean entering the function in debug mode.

Comment: Is `ls()` at the end of function insufficient? Do you mean you want to  get the variable list inside the function or outside the function?

Comment: I don't have the source to the function, so I can't put ls inside of it.  Imagine I want to perform this operation on a function in one of the base libraries.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but maybe close.
You can embed an arbitral expression in existing functions by `trace`:

```
> trace(lm, exit = function().last_env <<- parent.frame())
Tracing function "lm" in package "stats"
[1] "lm"
> lm(y~x, data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1))
Tracing lm(y ~ x, data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10:1)) on exit 

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10:1))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
         11           -1  

> ls(.last_env)
 [1] "cl"          "contrasts"   "data"        "formula"     "m"           "method"      "mf"          "model"       "mt"          "na.action"   "offset"     
[12] "qr"          "ret.x"       "ret.y"       "singular.ok" "subset"      "w"           "weights"     "x"           "y"           "z"          
> get("cl", .last_env)
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10:1))
```

Comment: Brilliant. "There is no if. Only how."

Answer (score 2):

To get all variables and their values as a list you could use the last line of the function in this example:

```
myFunction=function(){
  a="lolcat"
  b=data.frame(firstCol=1:3,secondCol=letters[1:3])
  d=list()
  d[["someName"]]=10:13
  sapply(ls(),function(x)get(x),simplify=F,USE.NAMES=T)
}

myResults=myFunction()

myResults
```

Output:

```
$a
[1] "lolcat"

$b
  firstCol secondCol
1        1         a
2        2         b
3        3         c

$d
$d$someName
[1] 10 11 12 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

```
> fjj <- function() { x <- 3; y <- 4; ls(environment())}
> fjj()
[1] "x" "y"
```

Or perhaps you would want a list where you 'get' each component.